# Associate a domain with a site in such a way that a security certificate can be installed on IIS 8.5

Tags: domains, server, iis, drupal, windows

I can not publish my website (created with Drupal 7) with IIS 8.5 (windows server 2012 r2). I'm forwarding my domain `example.com` as a frame to `http://192.0.2.4/mywebsite` (i got static ip).

Everything is working fine, except the certificate. So I need to customize the settings.

On the router is a NAT config, my public IP `192.0.2.4:80` is forwarding to server `192.0.2.44:80`. If you enter `example.com` you get `http://192.0.2.4/mywebsite`.

My objective is, to get working the website from IIS 8.5 with the certificate.

In total I have 6 domains, all of them have the same target website.

Binding in IIS is `http | blank hostname | port 80 | IP unallocated`

Comment: Do not redirect to an URL with an IP address in it. That is not the normal use case of HTTPS and you will have difficulties getting a certificate for this IP address, while you should have no problem getting certificates for a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use forwarding or redirects of any time.   You want the site to be served from your domain name.

To do so, assign a "host header value" to your site.   This associated the site with the domain name.

1. Open the site properties.
2. Click "Advanced" next to the IP Address
3. Add a new host header value for your main domain name that matches the certificate.
4. Set up forwarding for the other five domain names.

There are screenshots of the process here:
http://www.visualwin.com/Host-Header/

Comment: Tried without any success. Entered the nameserver of the domain but getting 404 error.

Comment: Don't enter the nameserver. Enter the domain itself.

Comment: Same result, getting a 404 error. What settings i need for domain DNS and server dns?

Comment: DNS needs to have `A` records pointing to your server's IP address.   Once you verify that, you need to configure your web server to recognize the domain and show the correct set of documents for it.  That is what the instructions above attempt to do.

Comment: Finally it's working and the green lock appears in browser. DNS record is pointing the server. Had to configure http/https NAT rules on router too.